# performing $project after $group in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

My group function is:

```
 {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$id',
            'averageD': {'$avg': '$D'},
            'averageS': {'$avg': {'$first' : '$joinedS.score'} }  
        }

    },
```

But I have lost variables from the output, for example 'name' associated to each of the unique id's. However can I get the output from the project or group function of `name` which appears in my collection as follows

profiles

```
{"id": 123456, "name": "blah blah"}
```

Comment: You can keep the field with [$first](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) in the `$group` stage.

Comment: @ray thank you. Do you have an example?

Comment: Does the [examples section](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#use-in-group-stage) of the page @ray linked answer that?